# how to resolve 302 Found error in ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

On deleting cookies of my application, my ajax call is not processing to the action of the controller which is correct. But it is delivering html as return type and entering the success block of the ajax call and showing that page. So I am getting 302 Found as the status code, but later on it is converted into 200.
Any solutions for that? Why it is not going into the error block of the ajax call ?

Comment: 302 is an HTTP status code for URL redirection. So you might have code in your action that redirects you in case you're missing a cookie.

Comment: In that how can i redirect my app to login page ?